# Simulating errorlevel

Tags: batch, exit-code

My command takes long to run but I expect that it can finish with error and I want fail fast in the batch loop in this case. How do I produce the error level?

I tried a batch file with `exit 1`. But, it closes the parent script regardless if it is called with `call raise_error.bat` or simply `raise_error`.

I also tried `cmd /c exit 1`. This does not close the parent script but following `if errorlevel 0 goto exit` and `if errorlevel 1 goto exit` both branch to exit. No early exit is taken in case of `if errorlevel 2 goto exit` or any larger number. How is it ever possible? I mean, how can I have two error levels at the same time? Aren't values of a single variable they mutually exclusive?

How do I inject the error exit code?